# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Last item not showing properly

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have a simple horizontal **CollectionView** which works fine except that the last item is not showing properly and i have to **force scroll it to see it**.

[image: screenshot of collection view with last item not showing properly]

I tried all kinds of padding and margins but the only property that will make it show is if make **ItemSpacing="20"** or bigger. The problem is that, if i added more items, the issue still will show again and this is a dynamic list.

this is the code for the stacklayout under the content page directly.

```
<StackLayout  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <CollectionView HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="5" >
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Open (Item)</x:String>
                        <x:String>Side Menu</x:String>
                        <x:String>How to?</x:String>
                        <x:String>Back/Cancel</x:String>
                        <x:String>Logout</x:String>
                        <x:String>Yes/No</x:String>
                        <x:String>App Info</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="DarkCyan" CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="False" Padding="10" Margin="0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="DarkCyan"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried ItemSizingStrategy property to "MeasureAllItems" of Collection View?

Comment: I believe this is the default setting but i will try to set it explicitly

Comment: Looks fine on my sample proj. What version of your XF?

Comment: This is a known issue on iOS and reported here : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11011. Collectionview is broken when items have different sizes and ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" , and the problem seems not been sovled so far.

Comment: The workaround is to use `ScrollView + StackLayout` with `BindableLayout` instead , see the [comment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11011#issuecomment-834678485) bares43 provided.

Comment: Or use https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.HorizontalListView

Answer (score 1):

i found removing ItemSpacing property make list items show properly.